# Group Properties - "$a$" commutes "$b$"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Dr. Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra" presents this problem from Chapter 4:

> If $a$ and $b$ are in $G$ and $ab=ba$, we say that $a$ and $b$ commute. Assuming that $a$ and $b$ commute, prove the following:
>
> 3. $a$ commutes with $ab$

I'm confused what this means to prove.

Given the above assumptions, does this mean proving that:

$$aab=aba\ ?$$

Comment: Yes, exactly that. And there is not really much to show, is there?

Comment: no, I suppose not. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should prove that
$$
a(ab)=(ab)a
$$
For we have
$$
a(ab)=a(ba)=(ab)a
$$